# "Tray icon" that displays network traffic

Tags: networking, icons

Remember ZoneAlarm?  Many years ago ZoneAlarm placed an icon in your Windows system tray that displayed both incoming and outgoing network activity by separate red and green flashing lights.  Very cool for those of us who were concerned about when our computers were talking to the world!

Is there any program that displays a similar icon on a Linux screen?  I am not concerned about numbers of packets or bandwidth, only whether or not any in- and out-bound activity is taking place.

[Added]  Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: What desktop do you use? MATE has a "network monitor" applet you can add to the panel that shows up and down traffic. https://i.imgur.com/iTkLD4o.png

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3.  I wonder if the network monitor you describe would work for me.  Many thanks for the link  --  I will try this.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop uses the GNOME desktop by default; have you explored looking for any extensions that do what you want?  https://extensions.gnome.org/